# Monitor has to be replugged on every computer launch

Tags: display

I recently got a new PC for gaming. I'm currently using the same two monitors that had no issues whatsoever on my last pc- a BenQ Zowie XL LCD, and an Acer SB220Q. Ever since I started using the BenQ on this new PC, it had a noticeable light gray tinge upon launch. An unplug and replug of the monitor fixes the issue, but it comes back every time I start the computer.

Specs:

- Motherboard - Dell G5 5090
- CPU - i7 9700 (8-Core, 12MB Cache)
- RAM - 16.0 GB
- GPU - GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
- OS - Windows 10 Home, 64-bit
- Bugged Monitor: https://zowie.benq.com/en/product/monitor/xl/xl2720.html

I was wondering what could be causing this. If anyone has any ideas / fixes, send them my way.

Comment: 1-Have you tried Acer on video port (DP, DVI, or HDMI) that BenQ is on to see if grey issue is seen there? 2-I'm guessing issues is something odd with video card, I assume it's new with this PC (not taken from old working PC)? 3-Have you updated graphics drivers?

Comment: The BenQ monitor is the only one with the problem. It's a new graphics card, so that probably has something do to with it. All my graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: I understand the benQ only has the problem, trying the other monitor with that video cable on that port will determine if it's the port, video card, or cable. It'll confirm it's not the monitor

Comment: I'm using a Display Port cable to hook my PC up to the BenQ monitor. I just checked the back of the Acer monitor and it seems like it only takes HDMI. So I'm still unsure if the problem lies within the monitor or the cable.